# Ubuntu taking to long to download?

Tags: 13.04, downloads

I've started the installation of Ubuntu, and after clicking on 'Install Ubuntu' it boots to window and asks me to choose a username, password, disk size, etc. it then brings me to a screen that says it will take Ubuntu 50hrs to download!!

[image: Screenshot here]

Please help me I don't want to wait so long!

Comment: Did you burned/created a LiveCD/USB?

Comment: well what's your internet speed? That's really the whole bottleneck .

Answer (score 0):

ok, if you want to make it quick, try to download Ubuntu ISO then make a bootable live drive. then, if you didint like to take that to long to install, make sure you turn off your wifi or internet for awhile, then it will skip the download procedure. "THATS IT" you make change or update or download once you UBUNTU setup is complete.